# Reference Workshop App Input Widget Value Externally (in a backend process e.g. Python Transform)

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is it possible to reference the value entered by a user into, say, a text input widget, in a backend process e.g. a Python transform? I want to be able to manipulate a dataset according to user input values entered into an input widget. Really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m not sure that is necessary to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can set up an action that writes whatever value the user input to a property of an object. This could either be an existing one or one that is created when the user is taking the action - whatever makes sense for your workflow. As a general rule, think of workshop as a place for users to interact with the ontology - both reading and writing - so if you want to store things they do in workshop you'll need to write to the ontology.

If you want to use it in a transform downstream you'll need to then materialise the dataset that backs this object type, which essentially captures all the ontology edits in a dataset. You can set up in ontology manager.

Comment: Thank you so much George! This could be a game-changer for me!

Comment: Will I need to use a writeback webhook?

Comment: No. You don't need a webhook. You need an Action (e.g. "Edit my object") on an Object Type, configured in Ontology Manager Application / https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/ontology-manager/overview/. You don't need to setup an actual API call.